# dirpagination does not return all rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dirpagination

I have 3 divs which creates tables as you can see from the following link:-
https://github.com/anirbanmishra/congress.php/blob/master/web_test

Then I have my javascript file as follows:-
https://github.com/anirbanmishra/congress.php/blob/master/javascript

In the javascript I set 3 $scope variables based on some logic. The 3 scope variables are $scope.users and it has 538 rows, $scope.house has 438 rows and $scope.senate has 100 rows.

I then use these variables to populate the table using dirpaginate. But the issue is that all the 3 divs produce just 100 rows. If I comment out any two divs then it gives the correct number of rows. But all the divs together gives just 100 rows instead of 538,438 and 100 rows.

I am pretty new to this and any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the  were going for the default pagination-id because I had not given any pagination-id. Created pagination-id for each div and then placed the  under each table with the respective pagination-id attribute. This solved the issue.

The changes in my code:-

`<tr dir-paginate="senate in senate|orderBy:['fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="bySenate">`

and

`<div id="controls" class="controls" align="center">
    <dir-pagination-controls
        pagination-id="bySenate"
        max-size="5"
        direction-links="true"
        boundary-links="true" >
    </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>`